# Using ActionBarActivity and Google Maps in same Android Application

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-appcompat

I am building an Android Application in which I need to use `ActionBarActivity` for making use of action bar on devices upto API level 8(Froyo). For this purpose I am including Android Support AppCompat V7 library into my project.

I also want to make use of Google Maps via MapFragment class in google_play_services library project.

Both library project are working fine, when I am importing them individually.
But problem is when I add both of them into same project(I want to use **`ActionbarActivity`** and **`MapFragment`** in same project). **When I am importing them both compiler fails to recogonize classes from any of the library.**
Kindly help.

Comment: Will you please post your logcat

Comment: How can I post my logcat if project contains error? @Reena

Comment: just copy your error display in Logcat window and paste here.

Comment: there is no need to use MapFragment simply use a mapview inside the fragment layout xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume name of your project to be `SampleApp`.
Follow these steps:
1. Delete `android-support-v4.jar` from the libs folder of your `SampleApp`.
2. Follow the steps given at  [Android Developer Reference](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library).
3. Add all the library projects you need.
4. Check if there is repetition of some kind of library in any of the sample projects. e.g. `libProjA` may contain `libProjR` and `libProjB` may also contain `libProjR`.
5. Remove the repitition if found.

**Enjoy Coding!!**

Comment: **Excellent** explanation!! Thumbs Up!!

Answer (score 1):

I think here problem is support v4 library just check it in all supported projects libs and if it present all projects libs then remove in all projects remaining AppCompact project. i mean it should be in appcompect project libs and remove in other projects...

Comment: No I have checked it. 'Support v4' library is added only in  'AppCompat v7' library project and not in 'Google Play Services' Project.

Comment: have you use FragmentActivity as Parent Activity instead of ActionBarActivity?

Comment: I want to use ActionBarActivity but it doesn't recognize it, this is where problem lies!!

Comment: hey add support v4 to your main proj and remove from appcompat. then try with ActionBarActivity dont use fragmentActivity.i think in your playservice library dont get support lib resources so error is occured so just try this thing....